# SNMP configuration on a Cisco switch

Tags: cisco, switch, snmp, monitoring

I need to configure SNMP on a Cisco switch and link it to SNMP 1.1.1.1 SolarWinds server. Please suggest commands for the switch.

We are using SNMPv3 with MD5 auth entication.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Cisco has all sorts of guides to configuring SNMP. For instance: [Configuring SNMP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12-2_55_se/configuration/guide/scg_2960/swsnmp.html). It is possible that some switches or IOS versions will vary. There are also some decision to be made, such as SNMP ACLs, which notifications, etc. You will need to make some decision and customize your configuration.

> **SNMP Configuration Guidelines**
>
> If the switch starts and the switch startup configuration has at least
>   one **snmp-server** global configuration command, the SNMP agent is
>   enabled.
>
> An SNMP group is a table that maps SNMP users to SNMP views. An SNMP
>   user is a member of an SNMP group. An SNMP host is the recipient of an
>   SNMP trap operation. An SNMP engine ID is a name for the local or
>   remote SNMP engine.
>
> When configuring SNMP, follow these guidelines:
>
> - When configuring an SNMP group, do not specify a notify view. The    **snmp-server host** global configuration command autogenerates a notify 
>     view for the user and then adds it to the group associated with that 
>     user. Modifying the group's notify view affects all users associated
>     with that group. See the Cisco IOS Network Management Command 
>     Reference for information about when you should configure notify 
>     views.
> - To configure a remote user, specify the IP address or port number for   the remote SNMP agent of the device where the user resides.
> - Before you configure remote users for a particular agent, configure    the SNMP engine ID, using the **snmp-server engineID** global 
>     configuration with the **remote** option. The remote agent's SNMP engine 
>     ID and user password are used to compute the authentication and 
>     privacy digests. If you do not configure the remote engine ID first,
>     the configuration command fails.
> - When configuring SNMP informs, you need to configure the SNMP engine    ID for the remote agent in the SNMP database before you can
>     send    proxy requests or informs to it.
> - If a local user is not associated with a remote host, the switch does    not send informs for the **auth** (authNoPriv) and the **priv**
>     (authPriv)    authentication levels.
> - Changing the value of the SNMP engine ID has important side effects.    A user's password (entered on the command line) is
>     converted to an  MD5 or SHA security digest based on the password
>     and the local engine ID. The command-line password is then
>     destroyed, as required by RFC 2274. Because of this deletion, if the value of the engine ID changes, the security digests of SNMPv3 users become invalid, and you need to reconfigure SNMP users by using the **snmp-server user** username global configuration command. Similar restrictions require the 
>     reconfiguration of community strings when the engine ID changes.

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy: https://thwack.solarwinds.com/docs/DOC-172650
And contact SolarWind tech support if you require further assistance.